# How to match this link on Android

Tags: android

How to match link https://example.com/example/. 
I try this:

```
<data
    android:host="example.com"
    android:pathPattern="/.*/"
    android:scheme="https" />
```

But this not working. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Good day!
Try to use android:pathPrefix = "/example" instead of android:pathPattern.
See documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking